# Passing date parameter to sqoop import into Hive table

Tags: oracle, import, hive, sqoop

I am importing a set of tables from an Oracle database into Hive using sqoop import statement as follows:

sqoop import "-Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true" --connect CONNECTIONSTRING --table TABLENAME --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --hive-import --hive-drop-import-delims --hive-overwrite --hive-table HIVE_TABLE_NAME1 --null-string '\N' --null-non-string '\N' -m 1

and i am using the following check column keyword in this sqoop statement for incremental loads:

--check-column COLUMN_NAME --incremental lastmodified --last-value HARDCODED_DATE

I tested this and it works great but I want to modify this so that it is dynamic and I dont have to hard code the date into the statement and I can just pass it as a parameter so that it checks the specified column and gets all the data after that date. I understand that the date has to be passed from a different file but I am not really sure what the structure of the file should be and how it would be referencing this sqoop statement. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sqoop job for the same.

Using sqoop job, you have to apply last-value as 0, it will import and update the data in the job so you only have to run sqoop-job --exec <> everytime, it will update the data without any hardcoded value.

```
sqoop job create <<job_name>> -- import "-Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true" --connect <<db_url>> --table <<db_name>> --username <<username>> --password <<password>> --hive-import --hive-drop-import-delims --hive-overwrite --hive-table <<hive_table>> --null-string '\N' --null-non-string '\N' -m 1 --incremental lastmodified --check-column timedate --last-value 0

sqoop job --exec <<job_name>>
```

For more details visit https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_job_literal

Comment: Hi I know I marked this answer as correct and it works fine when I hardcode the date first and then from the next run it is automated. But when I change the last value to 0 it gave me an error saying that the input value is not long enough for date format

Comment: Hi last value should be the same type of your selected column type, i.e. if your column type is a datetime then last value should be 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Let me know if it not works.

Comment: Using 00 in place of month, gives the error saying that "00 is not a valid value provided for month" however i was able to resolve the issue by just using the first last updated date from my oracle table.